# Meteorjs models/collections are accessible on client side. Security issue?

Tags: meteor

How to prevent users from acccessing/modifying client-side models/collections?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is too generic. Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: There's no way (that I know of) to prevent users from accessing client-side objects =\

Comment: Meteor 0.5.0 added `allow` and `deny` which do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Matt mentioned the work around is no longer needed. However as standard it appears the autopublish package needs to be removed to secure the system. The Meteor documentation covers securing the collections: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection

Answer (score 7):

Use [`allow`](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow) and [`deny`](http://docs.meteor.com/#deny) to define what database changes each client is permitted to make.

From the documentation:

> When a client calls insert, update, or remove on a collection, the collection's allow and deny callbacks are called on the server to determine if the write should be allowed. If at least one allow callback allows the write, and no deny callbacks deny the write, then the write is allowed to proceed.
>
> These checks are run only when a client tries to write to the database directly, for example by calling update from inside an event handler. Server code is trusted and isn't subject to allow and deny restrictions. That includes methods that are called with Meteor.call — they are expected to do their own access checking rather than relying on allow and deny.
>
> You can call allow as many times as you like, and each call can include any combination of insert, update, and remove functions. The functions should return true if they think the operation should be allowed. Otherwise they should return false, or nothing at all (undefined). In that case Meteor will continue searching through any other allow rules on the collection.

Comment: Additionally, to secure reads, just return a cursor whose query uses `this.userId` inside a `Meteor.publish` function. You'll also want to run `$ meteor remove autopublish insecure` to turn off the beginner options which publish all data to the client and allow most changes from the client.

Comment: As I learned today, you cannot use `deny` unless you also use also use `allow`. It is buried in the docs as "If you never set up any allow rules on a collection then all client writes to the collection will be denied, and it will only be possible to write to the collection from server-side code."